# What does the >> symbol mean in Haskell

Tags: syntax, haskell

I was reading the [Guestbook example](http://patch-tag.com/r/mae/happstack/snapshot/current/content/pretty/happstack/templates/project/src/GuestBook/Control.hs) for Happstack and noticed the `>>` symbol which I didn't see before in the textbooks I studied to learn Haskell (for instance see line 23). What is it?

I could not find it in Google because it ignores the `>>` totally (Bing does not but comes up with tons of non-related results).

Comment: hoogle (and hayoo mentioned below) are the best way to search using haskell syntax http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3E%3E

Comment: There's also Google Code Search which is generally good for cases like this although it may not be the best for this particular case: http://google.com/codesearch?q=lang%3Ahaskell+%3E%3E&hl=en&btnG=Search+Code

Answer (score 18, accepted):

At the ghci command prompt, you can type:

```
:info >>
```

And get a result like:

```
class Monad m where
...
(>>) :: m a -> m b -> m b
...
        -- Defined in GHC.Base
infixl 1 >>
```

From there, you can just take a look at the source code to learn more.

And just for the sake of answering your question:

```
k >> f = k >>= \_ -> f
```

Comment: I feel stupid now; I know about the :i (info) command but I come from Java and PHP and still am getting used to using REPL for everything. Thanks

Comment: Correct but barely helpful to a Haskell newbie. Why does it exist? What is it useful for? +0.

Comment: This is enough for me to find out where to search ; I didn't have any clue before.

Answer (score 47):

In do-notation

```
a >> b >> c >> d
```

is equivalent to

```
do a
   b
   c
   d
```

(and similarly `a >>= (b >>= (c >>= d))` is equivalent to

```
do r1 <- a
   r2 <- b r1
   r3 <- c r2
   d r3
```

Comment: As Haskell functions are generally pure, it appears to me that there is no point in evaluating a, b, c, or d in the above example, so Haskell wouldn't do it unless it contains side effects (IO etc), is this reasoning correct?

Comment: @Nearoo Not an expert on the topic, but I think you've overlooked that a, b, c or d could be pure (monads) yet still throw an exception, thereby affecting program flow even though their return values are ignored.

Comment: @Nearoo not necessarily, b, c, and d might not be evaluated depending on the result of a, and so on. Consider the following example using Maybe and `guard` (from Contol.Monad): `((\x y -> guard (y /= 0) >> pure (x / y)) 42 0) :: Maybe Double`

Answer (score 25):

Hayoo recognises this kind of operator: http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html

[`(>>)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:%3E%3E) is like `(>>=)`, in that it sequences two actions, except that it ignores the result from the first one.

Comment: The ultimate fist-fighting championship dukeout: Hoogle vs. Hayoo!

Comment: Thanks for the memorable URL! I've been accessing the site via http://hackage.haskell.org.

Comment: Considering Haskell evaluates lazily, does this result in no evaluation of the function on the left of `>>` at all?

Comment: @Nearoo: no, those are actions (monadic values), so they have side effects.

Comment: @SewerynNiemiec The side effect point probably only matters in the IO monad case?

Comment: @Hans No, it matters for every monad I believe. The main point of monads in Haskell is to denote a sequence of operations, which would otherwise be indeterminate with lazy evaluation. With the `Maybe` monad, `Just 1 >> Nothing >> Just undefined` results in `Nothing`, with `Either`, `Right True >> Left "err" >> Left undefined` results in `Left "err"`, with the list monad, `[1,2,3] >> [] >> [1..]` results in `[]`, and with `State`, `let f = get >>= put . succ in execState (f >> f >> f) 0` results in `3`. So any "state" may still get updated, and any "exception" stops further evaluation.

Answer (score 11):

From Hackage, `>>` is described as:

"Sequentially compose two actions, discarding any value produced by the first, like sequencing operators (such as the semicolon) in imperative languages."

I think a good example is printing two strings sequentially using `>>`. Open GHCI and type the following:

`putStr "Hello " >> putStrLn "World"`

This is equivalent to the `do` notation:

```
do putStr "Hello "
   putStrLn "World"
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm no Haskell expert, but `>>` is an operator that is used for working with monads, which are an unusual feature that (among many other things) enable imperative-style programming in Haskell.  There are many tutorials available on monads; [here's one good one](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/monads.html).

Essentially, `a >> b` can be read like "do `a` then do `b`, and return the result of `b`".  It's similar to the more common bind operator `>>=`.

Comment: Answering with "which are difficult-to-understand things" doesn't clarify. It sets the reader up for failure, I think.

Comment: Fair enough. They are now "an unusual feature" instead of being "difficult-to-understand things."

Comment: It's "an unusual feature" to call a function and pass the result to another function?  OK...

Comment: You're describing either plain composition of functions, which has nothing to do with monads, or a continuation, and yes those are also difficult for those coming from the imperative world to understand. All that aside: what Haskell topic has produced the greatest number of tutorials and newbie guides (often of the form "A Monad Is Like an X")? Why is that?

Comment: From a newbie persepective I found this answer informative. Monads are definitely a learning curve (aka unusual feature) for those new to functional programming